# How to make Socket.IO serveClient option work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'd like to use client distrubuted with the socket.io package in client-side scripts.

This is what I did:

```
const IOserver = io.listen(server, { serveClient: true, path: "/socket.io.client.js" });
```

But when I try to access socket.io client on that path `http://localhost:1337/socket.io.client.js` I get a 404 error.

How to properly set up socket.io to serve client side JavaSript file?

Comment: I think this is creating a listener only with the path of the listener ```socket.io.client.js```. You need to create an HTML file to hit it from the browser. Socket.IO is mainly used with Node.JS, how are you intending to create a server? 
See this to get a better idea: https://github.com/socketio/chat-example

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing what the path properties does. The `path` is the endpoint it should use to connect to your websocket server.

You need to manage the installation of the frontend js client manually. It does not get fed in from your server.

Answer (score 0):

I just met the problem.

If you want the serverClient option to work, you need to do as follows:

`http` version

```js
// app.js file

const server = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
});
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { serveClient: true });

server.listen(1234, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at http://localhost:1234.');
})
```

Or `express` version:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, { serveClient: true });

server.listen(1234, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at http://localhost:1234.');
})
```

And then, you can obtain the `socket.io.js` file by link `http://localhost:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js`, or `socket.io.js.map` file  by link `http://localhost:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js.map`.